# What could be the working of the statement with conditional operator?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()

{

        int x=2,y=0;

        int z= (y++) ? y==1 &&x:0;

        printf("%d\n",z);

}
```

How does the compiler take the statement int z= (y++) ? y==1 &&x:0;

Comment: If you have a book that told you to use `void main()`, get your money back. `int main(void)` is correct.

Answer (score 3):

in:

```
int z= (y++) ? y==1 &&x:0;
```

`y` is evaluated *then* incremented. Since the original value is 0, you're getting the "else" part of the ternary so `z` is 0.

Change to `(++y)` then you enter the "if" part of the ternary, and since `y==1` and `x` is not 0, `z` takes the value `1`

In that case it's guaranteed that `y==1`. It works with specified behavior because of the [sequence point](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#C) the ternary expression materializes, so the pre-incrementation has to have been performed.

> Sequence points ...
>
> Between the evaluations of the first operand of the conditional ? : operator and whichever of the second and third operands is evaluated

Such subtle and cryptic changes makes that code hardly maintainable. Don't do this at home.